# Why is string length not being considered when SQL Server sorts a string column

Tags: sql-server, string, sorting

I have a simple SQL fiddle at [SQL Fiddle for this question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d7b3/1).

**Question**

I am not understanding something very basic i.e. why does SQL Server place `abcx` before `abd` when sorting string values in an ascending order?

If someone could please explain the behind-the-scene logic followed by database engine, then this would be very clear.

I thought smaller length string would always come before a larger length string. So, first all strings of length 1 would be sorted, followed by strings of length 2 , followed by strings of length 3 and so on.

Script for this question is as below.

```
create table someStrings ( myname varchar(100) );

insert into someStrings (myname) 
values ('abc'), ('abd'), ('abcx');

select myname 
from someStrings 
order by myname;
```

Comment: C comes before D in alphabet

Comment: Yes, I get that. But, if it was abcx and abdx then it would be easy to understand. Why is smaller length string placed before a longer string? In this case, the two strings are of different lengths. I guess the string length is ignored when sorting on string values?

Comment: if you're comparing abc vs abcd.. then yes... abc would come first... but you're literally asking why does C come before D. Sorting operation does not take len into account .. .unless you explicitly ask for it.

Comment: SELECT myname
FROM dbo.someStrings
ORDER BY LEN(myname), myname

Comment: @Sunil - It is same as the attendance order in school. Will `Sunil` be ordered before `Pradeep` in attendance ? though sunil has lesser number of characters

Comment: Think about an index in the back of a book... actually think about how dictionaries work... does the word COW come before COMMA?

Comment: You are right. So it starts from leftmost character and sorts; then proceeds to next character and sorts and so on. I get it now.

Comment: COMMA will come before COW, if I start from leftmost character and proceed one letter at a time towards right.

Comment: @Sunil, and that is how string sorting works by default, by dictionary order, moving one letter at a time from left to right.

Comment: @Steve, Thanks for the explanation. I have been so much in the world of integers when dealing with SQL Server, that the string sorting mechanism seemed so foreign and complex to me.

Comment: @Sunil That's just how string comparison works. It's comparing character by character by ASCII code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are really discussing here is SQL Server Collation - have a look at this MS article - it's for SQL 2008 but as good as any for this point:

[Selecting a SQL Server Collation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) - how are you proposing selecting a collation will help? are you saying that it is just a matter of selecting the right one and they will get their desired sort order stated in the question?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I am proposing and saying that Coallition determines sort order.

Comment: Collation does not determine the sort order. It can affect the sort order but there is no collation that is going to have COW sort before COMMA (assuming ascending order). Yes the collation can affect some sorting in some strange ways but you can't change the collation and get the sort order the OP is talking about.

Comment: @SeanLange - the OP never asked about COW or COMMA - that was Sam Yi

Comment: OK. So how could collation make "abd" come before "abcx"? They did ask that and no collation is going to "fix" that.

Comment: That's a different question. The OP is not asking to put "abd" before "abcx" - Sunil is asking why SQL places "abcx" before "abd".

Comment: Right. So how does collation come into play there? I agree with @MartinSmith that your answer is not an answer to the question. It is a close topic but is not answering the question being asked.

Comment: I don't mean to pile on, but I do have to ask how you feel collation would affect this specific example. I can understand if the OP's initial question may have been "Why is `abZ` sorted before `abc`?" Collation would definitely be the reason there, however, I can't think of a collation which would result in longer length strings being sorted on their latter characters before a shorter string (such as the example we have here).

Answer (score 2):

When sorting a `(n)varchar` in SQL Server, each character in its **position** is sorted against those in the same **position**. If a `(n)varchar` is shorter than another, but its first character is later in the alphabet that another value, then that value will appear later in the sort.

So, for example, the simple value `A` is very likely be appear at the beginning of your sort order. Likewise `zAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` is going to appear near the end, as its first character is z.

In your example of `abd` and `abcx`, firstly the `(n)varchar` is sorted by its first character, `a`, then by its second, `b`. These are both the same. The third characters, however, are `c` and `d`. `c` in the alphabet, is prior to the letter `d`, thus in an `ascending` sort order `abcx` will be sorted before `abd`; because the 3rd character is earlier in the alphabet and is the first character that differs.

Edit: Also, to add a little more. If a `(n)varchar` is shorter than another `(n)varchar` but shares the same initial characters, it will also be sorted earlier. So, for example, the value `add` would be sorted prior to the word `addition`.

Comment: So, SQL Server takes the leftmost character of all strings and sorts them; then it takes the leftmost 2 characters and sorts; then it takes leftmost 3 characters and sorts; and so on.

Comment: @Sunil Effectively. I imagine it actually only compares the characters in the same position, not the character and all prior characters; someone with better knowledge of the inner workings might be able to answer that.